# Event listener doesn't work after adding a new element

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-listener, event-binding

Basically, I have a text box where I write some text, click "Add Post", and a new post will be prepended to a list of other posts (similar to Twitter). Each of these posts has a 'delete' button.

For now, when I click delete on each posts, I have a `console.log` that just says, "TEST". And it works fine. However, after I add a post, meaning, a new element has been prepended, the event listener stops working, even for the existing 'delete' buttons (not just the newly added one).

This is how I wrote the event listener for the delete.

```
for(var i = 0; i < deleteDOM.length; i++) {
   deleteDOM[i].addEventListener("click", deleteEntryCont);
}
```

...Where `deleteEntryCont` is just a function that console logs "TEST" for now.

`deleteDOM` is the variable for `document.getElementsByClassName("delete")` and is just a node list.

Here's the part where a new 'post' is added:

```
entryList.forEach(function(entry) {

        var entryItemDOM = document.createElement("li");
        var entryTextDOM = document.createElement("p");
        var metaWrapperDOM = document.createElement("div");
        var timeStampDOM = document.createElement("span");
        var deleteDOM = document.createElement("span");

        // Create entry wrapper & class names
        entryItemDOM.className = "entry";
        entryItemDOM.className += ` ${entry.mood}-entry`;
        entryItemDOM.id = entry.id;

        // Insert entry at the top of the stack
        domEl.entriesDOM.insertBefore(entryItemDOM, domEl.entriesDOM.firstChild);

        entryItemDOM.appendChild(entryTextDOM);
        entryTextDOM.innerHTML = entry.text;

        entryItemDOM.appendChild(metaWrapperDOM);
        metaWrapperDOM.className = "overflow-hidden";

        metaWrapperDOM.appendChild(timeStampDOM);
        timeStampDOM.className = "timestamp";
        timeStampDOM.innerHTML = entry.timeStamp;

        metaWrapperDOM.appendChild(deleteDOM);
        deleteDOM.className = "delete";
        deleteDOM.innerHTML = "Delete";


      });
```

Where `entryList` is an array of objects that this above code renders in HTML.

What could be the issue?

Comment: How you prepended new posts? there is a chance that you re-add all the posts when you prepended a new one?

Comment: Do you execute that loop every time after a new post is added? Do you reuse `deleteDOM` or do you call `getElementsByClassName()` again? If you're using `addEventListener()`, that means you're duplicating the event listeners each time.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant parts of the code where you prepend the new post? The problem might lie there.

Comment: @MátéSafranka No, the loop is only executed once the page is loaded. So I guess there's the problem. Because when the new element is added, there's no event listener attached to it?

Comment: @MátéSafranka I added that part in the above post.

Comment: That's right, when you call `getElementsByClassName()` and execute the loop, it only adds the listener to the elements that exist at that point. You have to add the listener to each new element.

Comment: @MátéSafranka How do I go about doing that? So when I 'add' a new post, in that same function, I must attach an event listener to the delete?

Comment: So attach it when you create it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you're only adding the event listeners when the page is loaded, which means it's only added to the posts that are visible at the time. You need to add the listener separately to each new post you create:

```
metaWrapperDOM.appendChild(deleteDOM);
deleteDOM.className = "delete";
deleteDOM.innerHTML = "Delete";
deleteDOM.addEventListener('click', deleteEntryCont);
```